# Normed space and convex hull of closed subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $(V, ||\cdot||)$ be a normed space. If $ C\subseteq V$ is a closed set we do not know if $ch(C)$ is closed or not.

The professor provided this example that as of now I'm not getting:
Consider the set $$S=\big(\{0\}\times[0,1]\big) \cup \big([0,+\infty]\times\{0\}\big) \subseteq \mathbb R^2.$$ As the union of two closed sets, $S$ is closed. However $$ch(S)=\big([0,+\infty)\times[0,1)\big)\cup \{(0,1)\}$$ which is not closed. I don't get how $ch(S)$ can not be closed.

Comment: If you draw a picture of $S$ and typical line segments with left endpoint in $\{0\}\times[0,1]$ and right endpoint on the nonnegative $x$-axis, you should see it.

Comment: It is worth recalling that the convex hull of a   *bounded* closed set C in $\mathbb{R}^d$ is, instead, always closed. Reason: it is the set of all convex combination of any (d+1)-uples in C (we don't need more points). Therefore it is a continuous image of the compact set $\Delta_d\times C^{d+1}$, hence a compact set.(Here $\Delta_d $ is the standard d-dimensional simplex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that
$$
\{1\}\times [0,\infty)\subset \overline{ch(S)},
$$
while
$$
\{1\}\times [0,\infty)\cap {ch(S)}=\varnothing.
$$